# IIS Redirect to Subfolder only if specified

Tags: web, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Thank you for your time. Please note that all folder specifics will go to their own separate domains each and anything else will go to one specific domain.

I am trying to redirect my website with some redirect rules and I can help but think something is missing.

Essentially,  I need

`website.com/newlink` to forward to `extwebsite.com`

`website.com/otherlink` to forward to `othextwebsite.com`

(And a few others that I will specify)

If not specified I need all others that don't match the folder specific request to `*.website.com/*` forward to
`https://www.Ournewwebsite.com`

I am trying to write these IIS rules and have been banging my head on a wall for 4 days. I've done a lot of research and haven't been able to come up with the correct answer. Please advise.

Comment: Learn how to format question body please, or others won't be able to understand what you were asking. Also learn FRT so that you can debug the rules you write, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I thought I was pretty concise on the question. And although the rules are the same, it is going in Azure as an app service. So there isn't actually an IIS to use.

Comment: Before applying such rules on Azure App Service, build a local IIS on your machine to test them out, where you can use all kinds of troubleshooting tools (Fiddler/FRT for instance). People who rush to Azure only trouble themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 rules to match different situations, you can use the following rules as a reference:

```
<rule name="r1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^newlink$" />
       <action type="Redirect" url="www.extwebsite.com" />             
</rule>
<rule name="r2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^otherlink$" />
       <action type="Redirect" url="www.othextwebsite.com" />              
</rule>
<rule name="r3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(?!newlink|otherlink).*$" />
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.Ournewwebsite.com" />
         <conditions>
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).website$" />
         </conditions>
 </rule>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to test this but is this for anything other than? 

<rule name="r3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(?!newlink|otherlink).*$" />

Would I want to add all of my url matches from the previous rules so it knows not to match them.

Comment: The pattern `^(?!newlink|otherlink).*$` means no match newlink and otherlink, except these two data, it can match any data. I put my test results in the answer.